# Почему не сравнивается элемент массива с вводимыми данными из клавиатуры?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Введите букву от A до Z: ");
        String accept =reader.readLine();


String[] mas = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o",
                "p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I",
                "J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        if(accept==mas[3]) {
            System.out.println("Mission compled");
        }
        else System.out.println("LOL");
        System.out.println(mas[0]);
        System.out.println(accept);
```

Здесь мы вводим букв **d** 
и программа должна вывести `System.out.println("Mission compled")`, но выводится второе сообщение, что говорит об ошибки.
Можете объяснить, почему при равных значениях, программа  не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнивать строки нужно методом `equals()`. С помощью оператора `==` вы сравниваете ссылки на объекты `String`. И хотя эти объекты могут содержать одинаковое значение "d", это разные объекты. Напишите:

```
if (accept.equals(mas[3])) {...}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Да уж, без теории никуда.